# VBA storing database values in variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write some VBA code in excel to go with my VB.NET program and I am struggling with the basics of VBA as I have not used it before. I found some code which allowed me to get the values from my temporary table and put them directly in appropiate fields in the excel spreadsheet. I am populating a purchase order document, so information passed over are things like subtotal, vat, shipping, total, etc.

This is the code I have used to populate a single cell:

```
'get quantity
strQry = "SELECT quantity from [temp];"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn
.Open strQry
End With
'append data to document
Worksheets("PurchaseOrder").Range("D22").CopyFromRecordset rs

quantity = rs.Fields("quantity")    'setting the quatity in a variable
```

The last line of code is my attempt of storing the value of quantity in a variable, which I need to use to calculate the sub total as sub total was not passed over to excel. The code to populate the cells works fine, it is just putting the data in a variable to manipulate which I am struggling with. Populating the cells directly from the database works fine, but I am getting an error on that last line.

After storing quantity in a variable, I would also like to store the cost per unit in a variable, remove the £ sign at the start using a substring equivalent, convert it to a decimal then times the cost per unit by the quantity to get the sub total.

I tried using this following code:

```
'get price
strQry = "SELECT costPerUnit from [temp];"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn
.Open strQry
End With
'append data to document
Worksheets("PurchaseOrder").Range("N22").CopyFromRecordset rs

costPerUnit = Right(rs(0), Len(costPerUnit) - 1) 'setting the cost per unit in a variable
subtotal = costPerUnit * quantity
Worksheets("PurchaseOrder").Cells("Q47").Value = "£ " & subtotal
```

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Its because `Quantity` field contains >1 value and you are storing it in a non array variable. Try storing it in an array or dictionary object.

Comment: Does `.MoveFirst` work to get onto the first row to read the `quantity`.  Can you use the Locals Window to debug the `Recordset` to make sure the field name you are using is right?

Comment: If there are multiple lines as suggested above then you would need both `Recordset` objects to line up and you could loop through them both simultaneously (`.MoveNext`), do the multiplications on a row by row basis and keep a running total.  Alternatively read the data into 2 arrays and loop through them.

Comment: What is the actual error message and number you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So until filling the of the Recordset you have done it correct and then you have to see that the Recordset is more like a table and can have none or multiple rows with multiple columns. 
First you have to check if the query returned any result or if the Recordset is empty (`rs.BOF` and `rs.EOF` are true). Then you would loop through the rows (`rs.MoveNext`).
To access a single value you can either give the index of the column or the column name.

The following example loops through rows and through columns but also extracts again the column "quantity" at the end:

```
If (rs.EOF) And (rs.BOF) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        For j = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
            valueOfColumnJ = rs.Fields(j - 1).Value
        Next j
        quantity = rs.Fields("quantity")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop    
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Recordsets have a cursor and any reference to the recordset is going to return properties (like the value of a field) based on where that cursor is.

When you called CopyFromRecorset, you moved the cursor to the end (EOF = True). Then when you tried to get the Fields("quantity"), there was no active record of the recordset, so you got an error.

You could have first done `rs.MoveFirst` if you have the right type of recordset. Then quantity would have equaled the quantity field from the first record. Probably not what you want.

There is not a one-liner (as far as I know) that will get you the total of all the fields in your recordset. You have to loop like Graffl shows.

What might be the better path is to use Excel. You already have the data in there, so insert a formula to get the subtotal you want.

```
Worksheets("PurchaseOrder").Cells("Q47").Formula = _
    "=SUMPRODUCT(P23:P46*Q23:A46)"
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can save Recordset to array

as shown below

```
 Sub Check_gg_date_time_Unique(i As Integer)
        Dim filmSet As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim filmName As String, lastrow As Integer
        Dim Varray As Variant
        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=Excel_to_MySQL_Maintenance"
        dbConn.Open
    
        Set filmSet = dbConn.Execute("select count(wono) from  maintennce_db.work_order where post_gg_date_time = '2022-08-30 14:21:37'")
        Varray = filmSet.GetRows(1)
        If Varray(0, 0) = 0 Then
        'Do whatever you want
        End If

End Sub
```